# Generate dataframe columns where each column is shift(-1) of previous column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create 44 dataframe columns based on `TAZ_1720` such that each column is `shift(-1)` of the previous column.

How can I do it instead of writing it 44 times?

```
df['m1']=df['TAZ_1270'].shift(-1)
df['m2']=df['m1'].shift(-1)
df['m3']=df['m2'].shift(-1)
```

[image: table]

Comment: Use a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with a dict comprehension.

Here is a minimal example with 4 shifts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TAZ_1270': [100047, 100500, 100488, 100099]})

#    TAZ_1270
# 0    100047
# 1    100500
# 2    100488
# 3    100099
```

```
df = df.assign(**{f'm{i}': df['TAZ_1270'].shift(-i) for i in range(1, 5)})

#    TAZ_1270        m1        m2        m3  m4
# 0    100047  100500.0  100488.0  100099.0 NaN
# 1    100500  100488.0  100099.0       NaN NaN
# 2    100488  100099.0       NaN       NaN NaN
# 3    100099       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
```

---

#### Re: questions in comments

> Why use `**`?

[`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) normally accepts the format `df.assign(col1=foo, col2=bar, ...)`. When we use `**` on a dict in a function call, it automatically unpacks the dict's `'col1': foo, 'col2': bar, ...` pairs into `col1=foo, col2=bar, ...` arguments.

> Why use `f`?

This is [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) syntax (introduced in python 3.6). `f'm{i}'` is just a more concise version of `'m' + str(i)`.

Comment: thank you!!!!   what      **{f'm{i}    mean?     why use **    and 'f'?

Comment: @rafine you're welcome -- see the updated answer for explanations on `**` and `f`